# Xamarin iOS SDK version blank

Tags: xcode, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I have a Xamarin.ios project setup in my Visual Studio solution. Yesterday, before i upgraded XCode on my mac, the SDK version was 7.1. Now, after the XCode upgrade, the SDK version is just blank, and the new SDK installed on my mac (9.3) is not in the list of available SDKs. I created a new iOS project in my solution to try, and for that project the SDK was set to 9.3, with 9.3 being the only available project in the SDK dropdown list. Does anyone have an idea about where this information lives on file? I have scanned through the projects, and not been able to see any information related to the SDK version.

Edit: now my project has magically refreshed itself to SDK 9.3. However, my question still stands. How does VS resolve this SDK, and in what file on disk can it be seen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ran into this yesterday too, where something associated with the Xcode upgrade cleared the value that was shown in the Deployment Target field in the iOS project properties (iOS Application tab) in Visual Studio.

What was worse was that with the value blank, upon build the app could only be installed on iOS 9.3, nothing lower.

This value is actually in the `info.plist` file:

```
<key>MinimumOSVersion</key>
<string>7.0</string>
```

But again, this value can also be set in VS project properties for iOS.

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

Comment: Ok. But the "SDK version" under "iOS Build" is what I'm talking about. Tried again today, and it seems that it derives it from the iOS build agent attached to Visual Studio. When my build agent was disconnected, it was blank - now my agent is connected, it's back to the agents chosen SDK. If someone can confirm this behaviour I can sleep at night :)

Comment: Yes this matches my experience. Sometimes it takes disconnecting the Mac build agent from VS, and reconnecting, to get these fields resynced.

Comment: Ok. Thank you. Kind of a weak spot.